# Элементы, каждый увеличенный на 1 на javascript

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы с каждой новой строчки звездочка увеличивалась на 1 до 10, т.е вот так:

```
*
**
***
****
```

и так 10 строчек.
Вот код, только тут они в ряд выходят. Я добавлял еще один цикл но не разобрался до конца. Можете объяснить как это реализовать?:

```js
var x = '*';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  document.write(x + '<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

```js
var x = '*';
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  document.write(x.repeat(i) + '<br />');
}
```

[Документация по repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

---

**Вариант 2:**

```js
var str = '';
var x = '*';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  str += x;
  document.write(str + '<br />');
}
```

Comment: а можно ли реализовать без готовых функций, то есть просто добавив новую переменную или еще как-то?

Comment: @Juicy ответ обновлен

Comment: я так же делал, только вместо document.write(str + '<br />') писал document.write(x + '<br />'). Спасибо.